# Trying to recursively move through binary search tree to add a node

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, binary-search-tree

I understand that to move through a BST you would do it recursively. Like moving all the way left then back track then move all the way right.I am trying to add a node but the syntax is confusing me as I am getting  that addTreeNode is expecting a double pointer, but when I add a double pointer in the recursive call it then says "node" is not part of a structure or union. I'm just a bit confused on how to manage these structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ADD_LENGTH 30

typedef struct treeType{
    int listingId, price, propertySize;
    int numOfBeds, yearBuilt;
    double numOfBaths;
    char agent[20];
    char address[ADD_LENGTH];
    struct treeType *left;
    struct treeType *right;

}bNode;

typedef struct treeFrame{
    bNode *node;

}bTree;

void init(bTree **tree);
void addTreeNode(bTree **tree, bNode *temp);



int main(void)
{
    bTree *tree;
    int numOfProperties;
    int i;

    init(&tree);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("library.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("fopen failed\n");
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfProperties);
    printf("%d\n", numOfProperties);
    bNode temp;
  //  for(i = 0; i < numOfProperties; i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d %lf %d %[^\n]s", &temp.listingId, temp.agent,&temp.price,&temp.propertySize,&temp.numOfBeds,
           &temp.numOfBaths,&temp.yearBuilt,temp.address);
    addTreeNode(&tree, &temp);
    //}


    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void init(bTree **tree){
    *tree = malloc(sizeof(bTree));
    (*tree)->node= NULL;


}

void addTreeNode(bTree **tree,bNode *temp){
    if((*tree)->node == NULL){
        (*tree)->node = temp;
        (*tree)->node->left = NULL;
        (*tree)->node->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(temp->listingId < (*tree)->node->listingId){
        addTreeNode((*tree)->node->left,temp);
    }
  /* printf("%d %s %d %d %d %.1lf %d %s\n", (*tree)->node->listingId, (*tree)->node->agent, (*tree)->node->propertySize,(*tree)->node->price, (*tree)->node->numOfBeds,
           (*tree)->node->numOfBaths, (*tree)->node->yearBuilt, (*tree)->node->address);*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

particularly the *Insert* section

> Like moving all the way left then back track then move all the way right

Nope, binary search trees are already sorted.

In pseudocode, you just do:

```
node search(value,node)

  if node_value == search_value then return node
  else if current_node_vale <  search_value return search(left)
  else return search(right)
```

---

`void addTreeNode(bTree **tree,bNode *temp);`

Tree operations modify nodes, and that node may be the root node, so you can't use a root_node as a representation of the tree. Instead, a pointer to a root node is used.

```
typedef struct treeFrame{
    bNode *node;
}bTree;
```

So if your functions need to create or modify your tree, your pass them a pointer to that tree, they need to work with a pointer to the tree, because if the root node changes, the change needs to reach the caller scope. So all tree functions should have the signature:

```
do_something( bTree * tree_ptr)
```

But some people, (like me ) don't like that kind of abstraction, so instead of defining a tree structure, or a typedef, they prefer working directly with root_nodes.

In that case, the signatures should be of the type:

```
do_something( bNode ** root_node)
```

Remember that a tree is a pointer to a root_node, so you're just adding another indirection to be able to change the root_node in case the operation requires it.

---

Finally your prototypes:

```
void init(bTree **tree);
void addTreeNode(bTree **tree, bNode *temp);
```

Are wrong, you either need a double pointer if you work with root_nodes, or you need a single pointer if you abstract the tree.

Comment: I tried looking up abstractions but I'm still a bit confused on what abstracting the tree means..

Comment: A tree **IS**  a pointer to a root_node, The same way a linked list **IS** a pointer to the first element. [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Data_abstraction) is hiding that from the users of your code, and saying, here is a *tree* , use it with these functions. How are the nodes implemented or used is not your business.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function to add nodes has the signature

```
void addTreeNode(bTree **tree,bNode *temp);
```

you can't use it recursively to add nodes to the left or right subtree: `bTree` holds only the root of the tree, the subtrees are pointers to `bNode`. Define a new function in terms of the subtree type and use it to implement `addTreeNode`.

```
/* adds the new node to the tree - returns root of modified tree */
bNode* addTreeNodeHelper(bNode *root, bNode *temp);

void addTreeNode(bTree **tree,bNode *temp) {
     (*tree)->node = addTreeNodeHelper((*tree)->node, temp);
}
```

The code you have now goes into the helper instead.

```
void addTreeNodeHelper(bNode *root, bNode *temp){
    if (!root) {
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    else if (temp->listingId < root->listingId) {
        root->left = addTreeNodeHelper(root->left, temp);
        return root;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does the `if(!root)` actually checks? I know ! means not but I'm still a bit confused..

Comment: it's a common way to write `if (root==NULL)`